# nginx try_files with static image or fallback to php file with rewrite

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite

```
location /image_mini {
#  try_files /static_images/$2.jpg;
  rewrite ^/image_mini/([^.]+)-00([0-9]+)\.jpg$ /image.php?a=$2 last;
}
```

I use this rewrite rule to display images on my website. For example, if I want to display Image ID #123456789, I would use https://www.example.com/image_mini/some_cool_seo_keywords-00123456789.jpg

Then, image.php will check if /static_images/00123456789.jpg is found in local cache, if not it will create the file.

I assume I would get much better performance if nginx could look for the local static file before fallback to image.php

I tried doing this with try_files but I am unsure how to extract the image ID from the URL and i'm stuck here :( Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use your regular expression in the `location` statement. For example:

```
location ~* ^/image_mini/[^.]+-00([0-9]+)\.jpg$ {
    try_files /static_images/$1.jpg /image.php?a=$1;
}
```

Note that the evaluation of regular expression `location` statements is ordered. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more. Also, [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) on the correct syntax for `try_files`.